# Make all words in string lowercases except first one

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string

```py
string = 'One Hundred Two Thousand Nine'
```

how can i make all words be lower cases except first word.

So output should be like

```py
string = 'One hundred two thousand nine'
```

Comment: You mean all words or all characters? Because the answer provided by Kostas is for all characters except first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built-in function to do this:

```
string = 'One Hundred Two Thousand Nine'
print(string.capitalize())
```

Comment: Wow that was easy, didn't know that, Thanx